# Getting Error upon building in visual studio 2012

Tags: .net

When I build a project through VS2012, I get this error every time:

> Error 17  Assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' uses 'office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll   OLA

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: May be this will work : Change the version in the project file. Look for Reference Include that has 12.0.0.0 for the dll in question

Answer (score 1):

In your project expand References and remove the offending Assembly and then right click on References and add reference to the right assembly.

[image: Add Reference to Assembly]